# Why is gson not able to convert this properly

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the following object in a json string:

```
{
  "links": {},
  "apiResponseInfo": null,
  "id": "6a88e822-d0dd-41be-be05-da8e55b99501",
  "actionId": null,
  "amount": 0,
  "currency": null,
  "approved": false,
  "status": "Declined",
  "authCode": "auth code",
  "responseCode": "30041",
  "responseSummary": "Card is lost/stolen",
  "threeDS": null,
  "risk": null,
  "source": {
    "id": "src_321435425",
    "type": "card",
    "billingAddress": null,
    "phone": null,
    "expiryMonth": 0,
    "expiryYear": 0,
    "name": null,
    "scheme": null,
    "last4": null,
    "fingerprint": null,
    "bin": null,
    "cardType": null,
    "cardCategory": null,
    "issuer": null,
    "issuerCountry": null,
    "productId": null,
    "productType": null,
    "avsCheck": "D",
    "cvvCheck": null,
    "payouts": null,
    "fastFunds": null,
    "paymentAccountReference": null
  },
  "destination": null,
  "customer": null,
  "processedOn": null,
  "reference": null,
  "eci": null,
  "schemeId": null,
  "actionsLink": null,
  "captureLink": null,
  "voidLink": null,
  "selfLink": null
}
```

I am using the sdk from [Checkout](https://www.checkout.com/) (version 3.4.0). Currently writing some integration tests. Essentially I have a mock server and have stubbed the response that the sdk calls and when my code calls a method in that sdk. The above is my mocked response.

But I notice that my code is not getting the mocked response despite the logs telling me that my mock server is returning my mocked response based on the request the sdk attempted. What gets returned is just some fields populated (such as the `id` but not the `responseSummary` or `responseCode`) on the object.

Having debugged it further, I can see where the mismatch is occuring:

This method is in the SDK:

```
private <T> T deserialize(Transport.Response response, Class<T> responseType) {
    T result = serializer.fromJson(response.getBody(), responseType);
    //a few small business logic here but nothing special
    return result;
}
```

When I debug, I can see the `response` argument contains my mocked response which is good and the `responseType` argument is the correct class im expecting. But after the serialization, the `result` variable contains not the same fields as my mocked response.
The `serializer` object uses Gson to deserialise it.. nothing special (it using the gson.fromJson() method).. but I can see the gson is set up with a few configs:

```
    private static final Gson DEFAULT_GSON = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, (JsonSerializer<LocalDate>) (LocalDate date, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) ->
                new JsonPrimitive(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)))
        .registerTypeAdapter(Instant.class, (JsonSerializer<Instant>) (Instant date, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) ->
                new JsonPrimitive(date.toString()))
        .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, (JsonDeserializer<LocalDate>) (JsonElement json, Type typeOfSrc, JsonDeserializationContext context) ->
                LocalDate.parse(json.getAsString(), DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE))
        .registerTypeAdapter(Instant.class, (JsonDeserializer<Instant>) (JsonElement json, Type typeOfSrc, JsonDeserializationContext context) ->
                Instant.parse(json.getAsString()))
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.of(ResponseSource.class, "type", true, AlternativePaymentSourceResponse.class)
                .registerSubtype(CardSourceResponse.class, CardSource.TYPE_NAME))
        .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
        .create();
```

Does anyone know where I can how i can overcome this or what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: You are creating the `Gson` instance with `FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES`, however the property names in JSON are camel case. This might be the reason why deserialization of properties like `responseSummary` does not work because Gson is expecting `response_summary` (unless these fields are annotated with `@SerializedName`).

Comment: Thanks @Marcono1234 ! That was the issue! Whoever downvoted this question has some serious issue -.- it was a genuine question and I provided quite an indepth amount of info

Comment: Glad to hear to that this solved your issue. I have added it as proper answer now to avoid that this question appears as unanswered.

Comment: It's possible that the downvote was due to inadequate research to narrow the problem down. It's got nothing to do with the mocking part as far as I can see - you could easily have reproduced the problem in a [mcve] with a shorter piece of JSON. That would have been a clearer question.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the Gson instance with `FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES`, however the property names in your JSON data are camel case. This might be the reason why deserialization of properties like `responseSummary` does not work because Gson is expecting `response_summary` (unless these fields are annotated with [`@SerializedName`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html)).